# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not initialize a collection

Tags: hibernate, lazy-evaluation

When I try to access my collection (List) the following way, I get the following error, even though I do it within same UserTransaction.

```
:::
EntityAccessorException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not initialize a collection
:::
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not initialize a collection: 
:::

                        List<Brand> brands = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
            for (Brand b : brands) {

                Iterator<BrandPromoDetails> i2 = b.getBrandPromoDetails()
                        .iterator();

                while (i2.hasNext()) {

                    BrandPromoDetails bpd = i2.next();
```

====================================================================================

Whereas, when I change it to as follows, it works. My database is Derby and I am using Hibernate as JPA provider and using Hibernate Search. It would be great if anyone can provide an explanation of this behavior.

```
List<Brand> brands = fullTextQuery.getResultList();

                    for (Brand b : brands) {

                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        List<BrandPromoDetails> i2 = em.createQuery("select x from BrandPromoDetails as x where BPDBRAND_ID = ?1")
                            .setParameter(1, b.getId())
                            .getResultList();

                        for (BrandPromoDetails bpd : i2) {
```

### Complete Stacktrace added:

Here it is..

```
[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.711+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Hibernate: select brandpromo0_.bpdBrand_id as bpdBrand10_11_1_, brandpromo0_.id as id1_, brandpromo0_.bpdCreationDate as bpdCreat2_1_, brandpromo0_.id as id16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdBrand_id as bpdBrand10_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdCreationDate as bpdCreat2_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdPrice as bpdPrice16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdPriceType as bpdPrice4_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdPromoCreatedBy as bpdPromo5_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdPromoDescription as bpdPromo6_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdPromoName as bpdPromo7_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdUnitPrice as bpdUnitP8_16_0_, brandpromo0_.bpdWOMPowerCondition as bpdWOMPo9_16_0_ from WOMPOWER.BrandPromoDetails brandpromo0_ where brandpromo0_.bpdBrand_id=?|#]

[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.742+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|29930 [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 22005
|#]

[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.742+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|29930 [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'java.sql.Types 91' from a data value of type 'int'.
|#]

[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.758+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|29946 [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] WARN org.hibernate.engine.loading.LoadContexts - fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext@a27c32<rs=com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ResultSetWrapper40@184aa30>
|#]

[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.758+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|29946 [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] WARN org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext - On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
|#]

[#|2011-02-23T22:34:04.758+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|com.wompower.backing.search.SearchRegistry|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|The log message is null.
com.wompower.entity.accessor.common.EntityAccessorException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not initialize a collection: [com.wompower.entity.brand.Brand.brandPromoDetails#1]
    at com.wompower.entity.accessor.common.AbstractEntityAccessor.doSearchInTransaction(AbstractEntityAccessor.java:137)
    at com.wompower.backing.search.SearchRegistry.getBuySearchResult(SearchRegistry.java:99)
    at com.wompower.backing.search.SearchBacking.buySearch(SearchBacking.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:121)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2345)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:1993)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:1941)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:729)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not initialize a collection: [com.wompower.entity.brand.Brand.brandPromoDetails#1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2173)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.iterator(PersistentList.java:138)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:334)
    at com.wompower.backing.search.SearchRegistry$2.execute(SearchRegistry.java:126)
    at com.wompower.backing.search.SearchRegistry$2.execute(SearchRegistry.java:1)
    at com.wompower.entity.accessor.common.AbstractEntityAccessor.doSearchInTransaction(AbstractEntityAccessor.java:121)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'java.sql.Types 91' from a data value of type 'int'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ResultSetWrapper.getInt(ResultSetWrapper.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readIndex(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.readFrom(PersistentList.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:1156)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnTypeConversionException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'java.sql.Types 91' from a data value of type 'int'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Cursor.getInt(Unknown Source)
    ... 76 more
|#]
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Hi Binil,just added the stacktrace in the original post.

Comment: looks like the derby driver is complaining that `getInt()` is called on a DATE column in the `ResultSet`. Are there any differences in queries generated by Hibernate for both cases? Also enable Hibernate logging to see which column of the `ResultSet` it was trying to read when the exception happened.

Comment: Thanks Binil. I'll enable logging and will see this.
From the stack, we can make out that getInt() is called on DATE. But in such a case, I would assume that my 2nd approach also should have failed.

Answer (score 0):

problem was with the OneToMany relationship that added an OrderColumn attribute on a Date value.. That created the problem. Once I removed, it worked fine.